# rspec testing request doesn't execute the controller/action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I have this rspec test:

```
RSpec.describe 'Navbar', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /close_navbar' do
    it 'returns http success' do
      get '/close_navbar'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

testing a controller/action:

```
class Navbar < ApplicationController
  def close_navbar
    raise 'closing'
    session[:navbar] = :closed
    head :ok
  end
end
```

I need this to test that the session is updated with the proper value.

but I don't think the action is being executed, in particular I added the `raise` line to see, and no exception is raised.

also the test fails because the returned http status is `:found`, not `:ok`

Answer (score 0):

checking the response body, I figured that the app was redirecting me to sign_in action, so that's why my action wasn't executed.

that is the correct behaviour, and I have test helpers to sign in a user in the tests. so I used these and it worked.